# Rails decrypt attr_encryptable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I used this gem to encrypt my attributes. My entire line consisted of this line in my model

```
class Profile
     attr_encrypted :name, :key => 'a secret key'
```

now what this does is gives my name attributes values of null. If i try something like this (which is important, because i need to decrypt some information for admins in my app.

```
Profile.decrypt_name(Profile.first.name)
```

I get a null value again rather than the original name. How do i decrypt this gem.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you don't need to decrypt it externally, the encrypted value will be stored in `@profile.encrypted_name`, and the value you need can be accessed just by `@profile.name`

this way the https://github.com/shuber/attr_encrypted working, did you mean this one?